# Back button to main activity raises "Unfortunately Application has stopped"

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity, onclick

**First of all, forgive me if the question has became too long :)**

I wrote a (very) simple program, called `TwoActivity`, and I got an error.

### The program

The program purpose is to ask user his/her name and print `Hello, <name>` in another activity. The program consists of two activities:`First` and `Second`. `First` itself consists of an `EditText` to get name of the user and a button to enable user submit the name. `Second` consists of a `TextView` to print the hello expression and a button to return to `First`.

This is the code:

`onClick` method of button in `First`:

```
public void onClickGoToSecond(View view)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Second.class);
    EditText e=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    i.putExtra(Second.M,e.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

`M` in `Second`:

```
public static final String M="message";
```

`onCreate()` of `Second`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("Hello "+i.getStringExtra(M));
}
```

`onClick` method of button in `Second`:

```
public void onClickGoBack(View view)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,First.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

I think other parts of codes need not to be mentioned.

### The problem

The problem is that, when I go to `Second` and touch the button, the program is force closed and gives error

```
Unfortunately, TwoActivity has stopped.
```

### My approaches

At this point, and after some googling and finding nothing, I made some **dumb guesses**:

- **Dumb guess #1**: Because `First` is the `MainActivity` of the program,
  I cannot make an intent to it.
- **Dumb guess #2**: Because `First` has been created before, I cannot make
  an intent to it *again*.

So, I changed the program to see whether my dumb guesses are really dumb. And they were, as I was sure.

### The porgram reworked

I added another activity, called `Third` to the program. I also added another button to `First`, so that the user can send his/her name to `Second` or `Third`. I also added another button to `Second` that made an intent to `Third` and created it, that is something like this:
`onClick` of second button in `Second`:

```
public void onClickNext(View view)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Third.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

`Third` is fully like `Second`. It has two buttons. First one makes an intent to `First` (so it is the back button) and second button makes an intent to `Second` and creates it.

### A more strange behavior

At this point, I got a really strange behavior. When I touch back button in `Third`, the program works correctly. But when I touch the same back button in `Second`, the program gives the error mentioned earlier. Further more, when I touch the button in `Third` in order to go to `Second` the program works correctly, too, but in `Second` it raises the error. Totally, the program works correctly until you enter `Second`. Touching both of the buttons in `Second` makes an error. I cannot understand what is the problem at all.

***Comment***: Note that if I press the back button of the phone itself, or if I make `First` parent of `Second` and use back button in action bar, the program works correctly.

### Update

This is the stack trace of reworked program when error is raised (This error is raised when I click the button (with id `button2to3new`) to go from `Second` to `Third`. The same error occurs when I click button to return to `First`.):

```
Process: com.example.mohammad.twoactivity, PID: 7564
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClickNext(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button2to3new'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3966)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19319)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClickNext [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3959)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4652)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19319)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
```

The second line says that I haven't `onClickNext()` method as `onClick` for button that takes user from `Second` to `Third` in my activity class, but I have:

```
public void onClickBack(View view)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,First.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void onClickNext(View view)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Third.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And this is part of the `activity_second` layout file:

```
<Button
...
android:id="@+id/button2to3new"
android:onClick="onClickNext"
...
/>
```

Comment: “Unfortunately Application has stopped” -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: My guess is: the method names in layout file and the java code do not match. Please add the layout of "Second" and the whole java code of "Second", if you want to keep your question short you could remove some of the stack trace :)

Comment: @0X0nosugar No. The methods names are the same in both files. See the updated question.

Comment: You and I know that you basically know how to write an OnClickListener and most likely it's something like a curly bracket in the wrong place which makes your app crash. Now remote debugging is not exactly efficient. So if you like you can [copy your code to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101472/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-mohammad-k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the full code which [mohammad .k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5295339/mohammad-k?tab=profile) copied to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101472/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-mohammad-k)

Note that the error message was

> Could not find a method onClickNext(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

So there is a method missing for *AppCompatButton*, but `Second` extends `ActionBarActivity`. Why is the button treated as *AppCompatButton*? Why only the button in `Second`?

Comparing the layout files, it turns out that the layout for the second `Activity` contains the line

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

And that's it: Our benevolent IDE (Android Studio?) generated the *AppTheme* as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

So the `Button` element in the layout file was treated as belonging to the *AppCompat* universe and behind the curtains the poor old deprecated ActionBarActivity failed to answer correctly when the runtime asked for the `OnClickListener` method...**BOOM**

**Solution**: remove the `android:theme`

Comment: I tried removing `android:theme` and the program worked correctly. But using `AppCompatActivity` as parent of all activities, especially for `Second`, does not solve the problem. Why? Should I change anything else - except activities themselves - to `AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: @mohammad .k - yeah, you caught me there. That was an obviously uneducated guess and it does not work. So I guess (no, I'm sure ;-) ) my answer has to be edited yet again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct / better approach to navigate to next activity, you need to give it a try.

Instead of specifying the function in the XML, you can use onclicklisteners for the button / view which will navigate to next activity. Look below.

**FirstActivity**

**XML:**
Remove the onclick from the XML.

```
<Button
...
android:id="@+id/button1to2new"
...
/>
```

**Java**

```
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

  EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1to2new);
  nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, Second.class);
      i.putExtra("user_data_1", e.getText().toString()); // user_data_1 is the key which is used in the next activity to retrieve the data.
      startActivity(i);
    }
  });

}
```

Then in the second activity

**SecondActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    TextView t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText("Hello "+i.getStringExtra(""user_data_1));
}
```

The above code will work fine for passing the data between the activities.

if you want go back or close the current activity, just press back press / use `finish();` in any of the click listeners.

Additional Links :

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

[Passing data](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html)

[Android intent](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)

Best wishes..!!

Comment: Yes. I know I can use my own listeners instead, but I'm curios to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Try remove your parameters from the function you are calling. Param View and pass empty parameter.